# How to mimic passing a file using python variable

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out how to mimic passing a file to a program and instead of passing the file pass a python variable that has what information the program needs in it.

The syntax I need to mimic:

```
msfconsole < setofcommands.txt 2>/dev/null
```

What I would like to do:

```
answer = os.system('msfconsole < ' + myvariable + ' 2>/dev/null')
```

I also would be extremely happy if someone knew how to interact with something like msfconsole over a period of time so that when the msfconsole shell is open I could continually get python to type different commands without have to relaunch a new application for each time I wanted to type a series of commands

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html

Comment: Check this thread hope it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720838/how-to-mimic-passing-a-file-using-python-variable/8720889#8720889

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead, of `os.system`, you should use [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html):

```
import subprocess
p=subprocess.Popen(['msfconsole'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate(myvariable)
```

Note that communicate will block until termination. In general, interactive-like communication with another process just via stdin/stdout is a hard problem, since you must know how the other process delimits ends of messages.

In the case of metasploit, you should use the [XMLRPC API](http://dev.metasploit.com/redmine/projects/framework/wiki/XMLRPC) instead of the interactive tool msfconsole.

Comment: The file I pass is in the following syntax: db_driver mysql \n db_connect *:*@localhost ok. Would I use the same syntax for variable and how would I add new command to interact with the open shell if my variable is predefined can I append new commands to the variable and they will be executed in order?

Comment: This is for the use of the nessus plugin built into msfconsole

Comment: If you have the data stored in an opened file already, just pass in the file handle as `stdin=`. But assuming you want to have the same effect as passing in the file, your variable content should indeed be the content of the file. And of course, if you modify the content beforehand, the modifications will have effect. However, msfconsole is not the correct way to script Nessus either. Have you tried [pynessus](http://code.google.com/p/pynessus/)?

Comment: I am extremely excited to try pynessus thank you very much for your response as it has really helped me. Do you know of a python extension of msfconsole the documentation for XMLRPC is very poor

Comment: Since msfconsole is a command-line program, and the XMLRPC API is better suited for use from Python, there is no Python library for msfconsole. However, examples and helpers for integrating metasploit via XMLRPC [do exist](http://ghosthunter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/metasploit/pymsf/).

Comment: Thanks for all your help it really has helped me :)